# Method FieldNameToFieldConstant runtime Error 1004

Tags: vba, runtime, ms-project

i had try make this macro for Microsoft Project is fine if work offline but if i try make work with project server the method return error 1004 in runtime. check the code above.

```
Function RetornaValorCampo(NomeCampo As String)
    Dim Campo
    Campo = FieldNameToFieldConstant("NomeCampo", pjTask)
    RetornaValorCampo = ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.GetField(Campo)
End Function
```

Tanks for any help. []'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `NomeCampo` as a parameter to the `RetornaValorCampo` function. When you call the [FieldNameToFieldConstant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860541.aspx) function, you pass `"NomeCampo"` as the first argument.

Because of the `"` characters, `"NomeCampo"` will always be the string `"NomeCampo"` no matter what you passed in to the `RetornaValorCampo` function.

Try:

`Campo = FieldNameToFieldConstant(NomeCampo, pjTask)`

to use the parameter value that you passed in